# Can I use ESAPI framework with Servlet 3.0?

Tags: servlets, esapi

I wanted to upgrade from Servlet 2.4 to Servlet 3.0. Currently we are using ESAPI in our application and would like to upgrade. 
Latest ESAPI release depends on servlet-api-2.4.jar. Does ESAPI support Servlet 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my application to support Servlet 3.0 and ESAPI seems to work. So it is backwards compatible.